# How to Upload images invoking web services PHP using POSTMAN or WA

Tags: php, web-services, postman, browser-automation

I am newbie using web service and I would like to achieve upload images to a website using Web Services ( It's an automation ).

Web page is this : www.milanuncios.com/textos-del-anuncio/?c=2103&m=1

I am triying to look the trace but i dont understand how it does function .

Can you help me to do this or explain me how it will function using postman or Wa .

[image]

WA need this :

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Those extensions do nothing but perform ordinary file upload requests to a http server. How that works is documented and you will find tons of examples for that. So what is your specific question?

Comment: @arkascha I know it has a documentation so my question is what custom headers and request body must i put there

Comment: You miss understood my comment. I did not refer to the documentation of those extensions. As said, they don't perform any magic but normal requests. I referred to the documentation of such requests. A file upload via an http request is a standard thing. It is well documented and you will find lots of examples for that, here on SO and out on google.